# Function to return Excel worksheet column designation works for all columns except for one column

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a spreadsheet with various heading names in row 1.  In Column number 36 (Column "$AJ$1"), the heading name is "Product Quantity".  I am trying to insert a column after that column that has a heading of "Total Quantity".  My code figures out the column number (36), passes it to a function that is supposed to return the alphanumeric ("AJ") designation of the column.  Within the function call, the function figures out that it should be "AJ" but when it is passed back to the calling routine, the alphanumeric designation is blank.  I should mention that the function and the passing back to the calling program works for all other column references, it just will not work for column 36 ("AJ").

What gives?  Here's my code.

Data Sheet snippet:

| Column AJ | Column AK |
| --- | --- |
| Product Quantity | Product Price |

What I want:

| Column AJ | Column AK | Column AL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product Quantity | Total Quantity | Product Price |

Here is the calling code:

```vb
    Dim rng1                        As Excel.Range
    Dim QuantityCol                 As String
    Dim TotalQuantityCol            As String
    Dim strSearch                   As String

    Set rng1 = Nothing
    strSearch = "Product Quantity"
        
    Set rng1 = xlApp_p.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

        QuantityCol = ColumnNumberToColumnString(rng1.Column)
'        QuantityCol = Columns(36).Address (My attempt to hardcode which did not work)
        xlApp_p.ActiveSheet.Range(QuantityCol & ":" & QuantityCol).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight

        'Label the now blank column (where the column after Product Quantity was) with "Total Quantity"
        xlApp_p.ActiveSheet.Range(QuantityCol & "1").Offset(0, 1).Value = "Total Quantity"
        
    End If
    Set rng1 = Nothing


Function ColumnNumberToColumnString(col As Long) As String

    If col > MAX_COL_NUMBER Or col < 1 Then
        ColumnNumberToColumnString = "ERROR":     Exit Function
    Else

        ColumnNumberToColumnString = Split(Columns(col).Address, "$")(2)
'        ColumnNumberToColumnString = "AJ" (My attempt to hardcode which did not work)

    End If
```

I am not new to VBA programming but I am new to submitting questions to stackoverflow.  Please help if you can.  Thank you so much!

I tried hardcoding within the function and outside of it but that did not work either.

I was expecting a column designation of "AJ" for column 36 of my spreadsheet.

Comment: I do not see any declaration or setting for `MAX_COL_NUMBER`. Being so i guess your function should always return "ERROR", but you are saying that it works fine with every column but the 36th.

Comment: Anyway, why do you need to extract the address like that? Can't you just find the range and then refer to `rng1.EntireColumn`? To be fair, in order to insert the column as you intend, you should actually use `rng1.EntireColumn.Offset(0,1).Insert` or `rng1.Offset(0,1).EntireColumn.Insert`. No need to specify the shift since you are inserting the entire column.

Comment: `Split(xlApp_p.ActiveSheet.Columns(col).Address, "$")(2)` ? (which would probably entail refactoring your function also to accept an Excel instance as an argument)

Comment: I have a strange bug where the debugger tooltip shows `QuantityCol =` instead of `QuantityCol = "AJ"`, and this only happens specifically for `AJ`. This happens even for the minimal case `Function Test() As String : Test = "AJ" : End Function`. But the variable itself was set correctly.

Comment: @EmilioSilva this is EXACTLY what I was seeing.  I did not think it returned anything until I put a debug.print QuantityCol in my code.  That's when I saw that the variable was being set.  I did this after I created the stackoverflow ticket.  Thank you for verifying that I'm not losing it.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey thank you for looking at this.  The MAX_COL_NUMBER is a public constant set higher in the program.  And I DID have an error in the new column creation which you pointed out.  Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: @SpectralInstance I did not attempt to change the function as I invoke it many times throughout my code.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You haven't defined `xlApp_p`, but by the looks of it it isn't needed anyway.  If the code is in Excel then no need to refer to the application.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to convert a column number into text.  You can use the column number, or in this case as you're searching and returning a reference to the "Product Quantity" cell you can just offset from that.

```
Public Sub Test()

    'Where we're searching.
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Set SearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1)
    
    'Perform the search.
    Dim FoundRange As Range
    Set FoundRange = SearchRange.Find(What:="Product Quantity", _
                                      After:=SearchRange.Cells(1, 1), _
                                      LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                      SearchDirection:=xlNext)
                  
    'If the cell reference is found offset by 1 column,
    'insert a new column and update the cell to the right of your found cell.
    If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
        FoundRange.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        FoundRange.Offset(, 1) = "Total Quantity"
    End If

End Sub
```